# Rest API returning wrong result

Tags: here-api, geocode

I was planning to migrate from the json API to the rest API, however, the results are not matching, the reverse geocode of the rest API is returning the wrong result. has anyone faced that issue before? Find sample below:

[https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=-32.05786%2C115.93382&lang=en-US&apiKey={KEY}](https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=-32.05786%2C115.93382&lang=en-US&apiKey=%7BKEY%7D)

```
enter code here {
"items": [
    {
        "title": "Reece Australia",
        "id": "here:pds:place:036qd63w-93b4e78634c7482aa36a7140fde9701b",
        "resultType": "place",
        "address": {
            "label": "Reece Australia, Thornlie WA 6108, Australia",
            "countryCode": "AUS",
            "countryName": "Australia",
            "state": "Western Australia",
            "city": "Perth",
            "district": "Thornlie",
            "postalCode": "6108"
        },
        "position": {
            "lat": -32.05779,
            "lng": 115.93393
        },
        "access": [
            {
                "lat": -32.05779,
                "lng": 115.93393
            }
        ],
        "distance": 13,
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "700-7400-0366",
                "primary": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

[https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?apiKey={APIKEY}&mode=retrieveAddresses&prox=-32.05786,115.93382&maxresults=1](https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?apiKey=%7BAPIKEY%7D&mode=retrieveAddresses&prox=-32.05786,115.93382&maxresults=1)

```
enter code here {
"Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
        "Timestamp": "2020-06-25T05:17:32.232+0000",
        "NextPageInformation": "2"
    },
    "View": [
        {
            "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
            "ViewId": 0,
            "Result": [
                {
                    "Relevance": 1.0,
                    "Distance": 2.1,
                    "MatchLevel": "street",
                    "MatchQuality": {
                        "Country": 1.0,
                        "State": 1.0,
                        "City": 1.0,
                        "District": 1.0,
                        "Street": [
                            1.0
                        ],
                        "PostalCode": 1.0
                    },
                    "Location": {
                        "LocationId": "NT_K800C2SShmW5hJiQktPlsB_l_133454375_L",
                        "LocationType": "point",
                        "DisplayPosition": {
                            "Latitude": -32.0578752,
                            "Longitude": 115.9338325
                        },
                        "MapView": {
                            "TopLeft": {
                                "Latitude": -32.05782,
                                "Longitude": 115.9337
                            },
                            "BottomRight": {
                                "Latitude": -32.05798,
                                "Longitude": 115.9339
                            }
                        },
                        "Address": {
                            "Label": "Bannister Rd, Canning Vale WA 6155, Australia",
                            "Country": "AUS",
                            "State": "WA",
                            "City": "Perth",
                            "District": "Canning Vale",
                            "Street": "Bannister Rd",
                            "PostalCode": "6155",
                            "AdditionalData": [
                                {
                                    "value": "Australia",
                                    "key": "CountryName"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "Western Australia",
                                    "key": "StateName"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "MapReference": {
                            "ReferenceId": "133454375",
                            "Spot": 0.66,
                            "SideOfStreet": "neither",
                            "CountryId": "1469256839",
                            "StateId": "1469256834",
                            "CityId": "1469263736",
                            "DistrictId": "1469282231"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Result given by Rest API is correct as you are getting accurate result at that coordinate.
while in JSON API you are passing proximities with `retrieveAddresses` which always search for the closest street address or addresses in the given proximities.

for more details you can visit the documentations for both API.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your message. However, the Rest API result was not correct, as we can see the postal code between the Json API and Rest API are different and it is about 7Km distant each other. I just made a new request to the Rest API and now it is returning the correct address. Please, let me know you have corrected any issue. 

https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=-32.05786%2C115.93382&lang=en-US&apiKey=API